# Sumologic integration on Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

**How do I get past the `401, Unauthorized` error from *Artifactory* when working with Sumologic integration?**

I tell Artifactory to:

1. Create a new client connection, which forwards me to the Sumologic website.
2. Agree to the service agreement and click 'Access Dashboard'.

After a delay, I get `401, Unauthorized` from Artifactory (not Sumologic).

I don't find anything in the log, so I turn to the great collective...WTH did I screw up?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: CUrrently 4.12.1.   We're planning the upgrade to 5, and were trying to do some analytics as part of the migration

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy?

Comment: Only for the docker repository.   Everything else connects direct.

Comment: I suggest scheduling a session with JFrog support, really hard to tell what's the issue you're facing, we'll know better if we see it live. disclaimer: I work for JFrog.